# Process Form with php Without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this form ( its a web poll) , with radio answers and I need it when submitted the information from  the action file (voting.php) to be printed on the same page WITHOUT refreshing! Please help me I've been trying so hard for few hours, because I'm new to Ajax jQuery and java and all that tricky dynamic stuff.

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="voting.php" method="post">
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="answer" value="answer1"><?php echo $answer1?><br>
    <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="answer" value="answer2"><?php echo $answer2?><br>
    <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="answer" value="answer3"><?php echo $answer3?><br>
    <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="answer" value="answer4"><?php echo $answer4?><br>
    <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="answer" value="answer5"><?php echo $answer5?><br>
    <input id="questionId" type="hidden" name="questionId" value="<?php echo $questionId?>">
    <center><input id="button" type="submit" value="Vote"></center>
</form>
```

Comment: where is the jqury ajax code that you have tired?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ if you're new this is a very good start, you wont regrat, and you can/should complement it with an amazing website called stackoverflow ;) cumpz

Comment: ANother place to learn jquery is Jeffery Ways 30 days to learn Jquery videos. https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your able to use jquery, you can do something like

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('voting.php', {$(this).serialize()}, function(data){
        $('#form').html(data);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First do whatever you are going to do with your data in voting.php. Database whatever, or just set it to echo out the posts in whatever format you want. echo $_post("answer")

then,Your jquery might look like this

```
$(function() {
$('#myform').on('submit', function(){
var that = $(this),
url = that.attr('action'),
type = that.attr('method'),
data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
var that = $(this),
name = that.attr('name'),
value = that.val();
data[name] = value;
});
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: type,
data: data,
success: function(responce){
  $('#display').html(responce).delay(6000).fadeOut(1000);
  }
});
return false;
});
});
```

the #display is the Div#display you will make to display your results from voting.php, Whatever you echo in voting.php will be displayed in #display

Get rid of the echo $answer stuff

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation, i will try this code later!

I cannot get rid of echo $answer1..5 cuz these vars are defined before the form, i SELECT them from my database, so it's not a problem i guess